# Can I run a CUDA Program on a computer if I remote into it using Windows RDP?

Tags: cuda

I have a server that is located elsewhere.  On that server, I plan to run a program written to take advantage of the CUDA-capable graphics card on that physical machine.  This program has nothing to do with graphics--it will only use the graphics card for computational math.

Will I be able to run this program on that machine?  Will the program recognize the physical graphics card if I am logged in using windows remote desktop?  Or will the server not even recognize that there is a graphics card plugged in since I am remoting in?

EDIT: I wanted to mention that all computation will take place remotely and that nothing on this machine depends on what's going on locally on my home PC.  I am simply using my home PC to "view" what is going on at that server.

Answer (score 14):

You cannot use Remote Desktop to run CUDA.  Remote Desktop unloads the graphics driver which disables CUDA.

You need to use VNC or Splashtop or something else instead of Remote Desktop.

Comment: Awesome.  VNC sounds good.  One more question, though: Can I run CUDA code on the remote graphics card and still use it to display what's going on through VNC?  Basically, does using a graphics card for CUDA code eliminate the possibility of using it for any other purpose, like display?

Comment: Yes, you can run CUDA on the same card being used for display.  And in fact, with recent versions of Nsight, you can actually debug CUDA on the same card being used for display.

Comment: Awesome!  Do you have a recommended VNC server/client?  I am looking for something that is literally as smooth as RDP.

Comment: Actually, would I just be able to use rCUDA?  Would that do the job?  Or is that not what I'm looking for?

Comment: This is not actually correct. You *can* use CUDA over remote desktop on a Tesla device since Tesla devices use the TCC mode by default, as such they are not limited by the WDDM graphics driver restrictions.

Comment: Will TeamViewer work?

Comment: New NVIDIA drivers (r352 and newer)  have worked around the RDP limitation, and using one of those drivers should now enable visibility of a *supported* CUDA WDDM GPU in a RDP session.

Answer (score 10):

RDP runs in Session 0 -- just like a service. Graphics drivers aren't accessible from Session 0, so normally CUDA programs won't work (because they won't be able to access the underlying hardware).

If you're using a Tesla, you can put the driver into Tesla Compute Cluster (TCC) mode and bypass this issue, so any CUDA programs will work just fine over RDP.

Comment: Not a Tesla, unfortunately.  I think I will use VNC as suggested by Mark.  But will I be able to run CUDA code AND use the graphics card for the VNC display?

Comment: You should be able to do that, yes. However, the display will likely still pause (i.e., not update) while your kernels are running -- just like they would if you were physically sitting at the machine.

Comment: Yikes.  My program might be running all day long.  If I upgrade to a Tesla and switch it over to TCC mode while using RDP, would the display still pause?  By the way, your website/program looks really cool.  I will have to look into it.

Comment: It's OK if your program is running all day long -- many kernels complete quickly enough that you won't notice the lag. In general, if you plan to be computing 24/7 it's best to get a Tesla though (for a number of reasons) -- one of which is that the display won't pause if you run the Tesla in TCC mode (whether you use the machine directly or via RDP).

Comment: You can run CUDA in session 0, but you have to jump through some ugly hoops: http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=93450&st=0. As Jack says Tesla devices use TCC (it's actually the default in most cases) which takes them out of WDDM control and hence allows RDP to work. Some Quadro devices support TCC, but for Geforce VNC is your best bet.

Comment: I think I am going to upgrade to a Tesla!  One question though: Do I have to make any changes to my program to get it to run on a Tesla?  Will the program be able to tell the difference?  And does anyone know if Tesla cards are only compatible with specific motherboards?  Or do I just need a PCI-E 2.1 X16 slot?

Comment: You don't need to change your program, although if you have both Geforce and Tesla in the same machine you should check you're using the right one (not a problem via RDP of course since Geforce is not visible). In terms of compatibility, for the desktop Tesla cards you should be fine as long as the slot is double-height.

Comment: Jack and Tom, thank you so much for all the help.  Just one last question to confirm: if my motherboard has no integrated graphics, will my Tesla be able to power the display over RDP and be used for running my CUDA program?  Will everything work seamlessly?  You've been a colossal help.

Comment: Actually one more question: what is the difference between the desktop and server Tesla cards?  Is compatibility limited by the motherboard or is it something else?

Comment: If your motherboard has no integrated graphics, I *think* Windows will default to using a software-based renderer for RDP, but you should try it without the Tesla first to be sure -- in TCC mode, Tesla cards don't do *any* rendering of display graphics. You might also check Google to see if you can dig up any information on running headless Windows Server boxes -- that may provide some answers for you.

Comment: The only difference between the desktop/workstation cards (C-series) and the server cards (M-series) is the form factor -- the M-series cards aren't shrouded and they may have a slightly different heatsink because they're designed to fit within a server chassis where space is at a premium. Computationally, they're identical.

Comment: Oh that's not good!  I don't know if I have room for another card in my server!  I was depending on the Tesla to be both a simple graphics card and a computing cluster!

Comment: Jack, is your GPU.NET program still supported?  I am interested in using it once I get the Tesla card.  I can't email/call you using the info on your website.

Comment: @eek142 Sorry about that -- we've been having some server issues the last few weeks. GPU.NET is still supported -- please contact me at `jack.pappas@tidepowerd.com` and I'll be happy to provide more info about it.