# No CUDA-capable device is detected

Tags: windows, cuda, nvidia

I am new to CUDA programming, and I am completely stuck.  When I try to run either the supplied *deviceQuery* utility or one of the sample applications, I get the following error:

```
cudaGetDeviceCount returned 38
no CUDA-capable device is detected.
```

I am using Windows 7, 64-bit.  I installed Visual Studio 2012, and then CUDA 5.0 64 bit.  My graphics card is an NVIDIA GeForce GTS 250.  Today I went to the NVIDIA site and re-installed the most recent drivers for the card.

I can't find any support for this error in Windows beyond "ensure you have a working driver installed".  Does anyone have an idea of what could be wrong?

Comment: Do you have other graphics cards in your system besides the GTS 250?  If so please provide a complete description of your setup.  Are you connecting to this system remotely via RDP or are you working on the system from the local keyboard and display attached to the system?

Comment: I have no other graphics cards in the system beyond the integrated graphics on the motherboard.  I am using the GeForce GTS 250 as my display adapter.  I AM connecting to the system remotely (it's a work computer and I'm at home for the weekend).  I have not tried deviceQuery at the local keybaord/display yet - could that be the problem?

Comment: Yes [that is the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304082/can-i-run-a-cuda-program-on-a-computer-if-i-remote-into-it-using-windows-rdp).

Comment: Thanks, that ends much frustration in googling this error code.  I'll work on other projects over RDP instead.

Comment: This question should be reopened, in my opinion, because it is directly related to programming work.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum This is an application support issue as described in comments and an answer, thus it should be on Super User.

Comment: @JasonMArcher I think the issue of reopening is important, so I'll add that this question discusses a programming issue - a function (`cudaGetDeviceCount()`) and its return value.  It turns out that the *answer* relates to the system setup.  The question, however, is that of a programmer who encountered a programming error.  There is overlap between the StackExchange sites.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Run a cuda code using remote Desktop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882124/how-to-run-a-cuda-code-using-remote-desktop)

Answer (score 6):

The problem as discussed in the comments is that you are trying to run a CUDA session on a machine that you are connecting to via RDP.  This won't work with a WDDM device.  Please refer to [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304082/can-i-run-a-cuda-program-on-a-computer-if-i-remote-into-it-using-windows-rdp) for more discussion about it and suggestions for possible work-arounds.   Unfortunately TCC mode won't be an option for you since you're using a GeForce device, but if you can switch to VNC or some other remoting method, you may have good results.

**EDIT:**

Note that using some magic which I cannot explain, NVIDIA has recently introduced new windows GPU drivers which may (should) work around the above limitation.  Using recent NVIDIA drivers for your GPU should now be an alternative to enable usage of the GPU even in an RDP session.  This capability would only apply to recent CUDA GPUs for which there is recent driver support (i.e. 353.xx or newer, r352 and newer).  So cc2.0 GPUs should be supported, but driver support for cc1.x GPUs ended some time ago, so these older GPUs will not be able to take advantage of this capability.